# artisan route:list doesn't work with auth in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-artisan

Here is a piece from my LeaderRepository:

```
public function me(): Leader
{
    return Leader::find(auth()->id());
}
```

When I run *php artisan route:list* I get error that the method should return Leader but returns null instead. (*auth()->id()* is null)

It is because artisan command runs all the endpoint methods while beeing unauthenticated.
Any idea how to force artisan to act as system user or how to bypass exceptions like this?

in b4, im not interested in method returning *: Leader | null* instead of *: Leader*

Comment: No, it is not. `auth()->id()` is a valid method.

Comment: is the route to this method wrapped in auth middleware (eg do you have to be logged in for this method to be called?)

Comment: Yes. This was the case. php artisan route:list runs controllers method but there was no uthenticated user performing operation so auth() returned null.

Comment: can you post your full web.php

Comment: I don't have any. I just put if auth()->user() before that Eloquent query and now works fine.